# Why the restrictions in the definition of Berkeley cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

> A cardinal κ is a Berkeley cardinal, if for any transitive set $M$ with $κ∈M$ and any ordinal $α<κ$ there is an elementary embedding $j : M → M$ with $\alpha<\text{crit}(j)<\kappa$.

My question is about the restrictions involved in that definition of $\kappa \in M$? and of $M$ being *transitive*? and of $M$ being a *set*? why not the following?

**....if for any *class* $M$ with $κ \subseteq M$ and any ordinal $α<κ$ there is an elementary embedding $j : M → M$ with $\alpha<\text{crit}(j)<\kappa$.**

Where the underlying theory is $MK$ like, with the axiom of limitation of size replaced by an axiom of limitation of size on sets, more specifically any class that is subnumerous to a set, is a set. And of course without $AC$.

Comment: I think assuming the condition for every class doesn't immediately lead to a contradiction, but it might increase the strength of the notion - suppose there is an inaccessible $\lambda$ above a Berkeley $\kappa$. Consider $V_\lambda$ - every class in it is a set in $V$, and an elementary embedding from it to itself is again a class in $V_\lambda$, so $V_\lambda$ satisfies the Berkeley condition for all classes. One reason for restricting the definition to sets is that it turns the notion into something expressible in ZF - you can't quantify, not even explicitly talk about, classes there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dropping transitivity doesn't actually add anything: given $M\supseteq\kappa$, just consider $\hat{M}=$ the Mostowski collapse of $M$. Given $\alpha<\kappa$ and $j:\hat{M}\rightarrow \hat{M}$ nontrivial elementary with $\alpha<crit(j)<\kappa$, $j$ lifts to a nontrivial elementary embedding $\hat{j}$ of $M$ into itself with $\alpha<crit(\hat{j})<\kappa$. So if $\kappa$ is Berkeley in the usual sense, it's Berkeley in the nontransitive sense too.

Finally, if you drop transitivity *and* replace "$\kappa\subseteq M$" by the original "$\kappa\in M$," then the argument above breaks down but the notion becomes inconsistent: taking $M=\{\kappa\}$ doesn't leave room for *any* nontrivial elementary embeddings, for example, let alone ones with critical points (and we can cook up less-silly examples too).

---

I had a stupid moment earlier, where I mixed up ZF and ZFC - it's not immediately obvious to me now that replacing "set" with "class" results in inconsistency. I suspect it does however.

Comment: The question is definitely in the context of ZF, not ZFC. In ZFC we already have a problem by taking $M=V_{\kappa+2}$.

Comment: You quoted Kunen's inconsistency theorem.

Comment: @Wojowu Yeah I noticed that just as I finished typing :P. Fixed!

Comment: it is much shorter to say $\kappa \subseteq M$ than saying $M$ is transitive and $\kappa \in M$. What remain is the class condition?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Yes, but I don't think efficiency is always the highest goal. Focusing explicitly on transitive sets makes the picture easier to think about, in my opinion; we don't have to pay attention to Mostowski collapses. It also plays more nicely with other notions where transitivity/$\ni\kappa$ is more important. Re: the class condition, like I said (in my edit) I don't know.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm confused. As I understand, the Mostowski collapse is used to take a set $X$ with a well-founded, extensional binary relation $R$, and build an isomorphic transitive set $\hat X$ such that $(X,R)$ is isomorphic to $(\hat X,\in)$. I think you're saying to take $(X,R) = (M,\in)$ and Mostowski collapse. But if $M$ is not transitive, then $(M,\in)$ need not be extensional -- e.g. take $M = \kappa^+ \cup \{\{\{1\}\}\}$, where $\emptyset \in M$ and $\{\{1\}\} \in M$ have the same elements in $M$. So the Mostowski collapse of $M$ in the sense I understand doesn't exist...

Comment: Unless I'm wildly off-base -- when we say "elementary embedding from $M$ to $M$" we mean "elementary embedding from $(M,\in)$ to $(M,\in)$", right? Another issue is it seems to me that if $M$ is not transitive, then a nontrivial elementary embedding $(M,\in) \to (M,\in)$ might not move any ordinals... It seems like the Mostowski collapse would be more relevant to the question of generalizing the Berkeley condition to $(M,R)$ where $R \neq \in$...